# siunitx: spacing between \num and a variable name

Tags: spacing, siunitx

I am using `siunitx` to typeset numbers and units. But when typesetting numbers in front of a variable, I feel a thin space is missing.

For example, with `\num{0.1234}a` I get (1), and with `\num{0.1234}\,a` I get (2) which looks better. Is there a way to automate this or do I have to manually put a thin space after each number?

[image]

Comment: Assuming that `a` is some sort of unit you should use `\SI{0.1234}{a}`.   Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I defined `\mynum` for you which checks if the next token is of catcode “letter”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \mynum { o m }
 {
  \num [ #1 ] { #2 }
  \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NT \c_catcode_letter_token { \, }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Normal behaviour (very recommended)
\begin{equation}
  \num{0,1234}\,a
\end{equation}
Desired behaviour
\begin{equation}
  \mynum{0,1234}a
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

You can also override the `\num` command provided by `siunitx`, which is *not recommended*.  Therefore, I copied the definition of `\num` from `siunitx.sty` and appended the relevant bits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand \num { o m }
 {
  % begin from siunitx.sty
  \leavevmode
  \group_begin:
   \IfNoValueF {#1}
    { \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1} }
   \__siunitx_number_output:n {#2}
  \group_end:
  % end from siunitx.sty
  \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NT \c_catcode_letter_token { \, }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\num{0,1234}a$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: What about `$\num{0.1234} a$`?

Comment: @egreg That is why it is not recommended.  Or use `\peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NT`.

Comment: You might use `\peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NT`

Comment: As I explained in the other question, _do not_ save and redirect `\num`, instead look at how it's defined and base your new version on the code-level functions (yes, I know they are marked as 'internal').

Comment: Well, you guys are way above my level. Redefining `\num` seems indeed a bit too much. I was looking for a simple way to automatically generate a thin space between a variable name and a leading coefficient. I guess I will put thin spaces manually.